# Against the Storm passive effects

Tags: against-the-storm

Example a bathhouse has passive good health and regular baths. Is cosmetics recipe and workers required to activate those effects? Or is just building the building enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passive effects become active if enough workers are in the building. You don't need the resources to get the bonus (but you do need them for the resolve bonus).

The bath house has two bonuses. The first needs at least one worker, the second needs three.

[image: A bath house]

In this image, Regular Baths is active. Good Health is not, but would be if I added another two workers.

Note that multiple copies of the same city building do not stack.